# How can I pivot Rows to Columns with marking the pre and post events?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have this table:

| ID | EYE | DATE | 1ST_INJECTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Right | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 111 | Right | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| 111 | Left | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| 111 | Left | 2020-01-08 | 1 |
| 111 | Right | 2020-01-12 | 0 |
| 111 | Left | 2020-01-16 | 0 |

What I want is a table that splits the '1st_Injection' Column to 'Left_Eye_1st_Injection' and 'Right_Eye_1st_Injection' columns, and marking them like that

- The ones before the 1st_Injection is 0
- 1st_Injection is 1
- The ones after the 1st_Injection is 2

Desired output:

| ID | Eye | Date | Left_1st_Injection | Right_1st_Injection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Right | 2020-01-01 | NULL | 0 |
| 111 | Right | 2020-01-03 | NULL | 1 |
| 111 | Left | 2020-01-05 | 0 | NULL |
| 111 | Left | 2020-01-08 | 1 | NULL |
| 111 | Right | 2020-01-12 | NULL | 2 |
| 111 | Left | 2020-01-16 | 2 | NULL |

What I've tried is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N 'TEMPDB.DBO. #1st_Injection') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #1st_Injection

SELECT 
    ID, 
    Eye, 
    Date, 
    NULL AS 'Left_1st_Injection', 
    '1' AS 'Right_1st_Injection' 
INTO 
    #1st_Injection
FROM 
    My_Table 
WHERE 
    1st_Injection = 1 
    AND Eye = 'Right' 
UNION 
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Eye, 
    Date, 
    '1', 
    NULL
FROM 
    My Table
WHERE 
    1st_Injection = 1
    AND Eye = ' Left '
```

And then I couldn't figure out how I can insert '2' and '0'.

Please can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can LEFT JOIN the table on itself with the conditions same id, same eye,  date before the driving one, and 1ST_INJECTION of the JOINed one to 1:
if the JOINed ID is not null you have to add 2 to 1ST_INJECTION else 0.

```
with data(ID,EYE,DAT,inject1) as
(
    select 111, 'Right', (cast('20200101' as datetime)), 0 union all
    select 111, 'Right', (cast('20200103' as datetime)), 1 union all
    select 111, 'Left', (cast('20200105' as datetime)), 0 union all
    select 111, 'Left', (cast('20200108' as datetime)), 1 union all
    select 111, 'Right', (cast('20200112' as datetime)), 0 union all
    select 111, 'Left', (cast('20200116' as datetime)), 0 -- union all
)
select d1.id, d1.eye, d1.dat, 
    CASE WHEN d2.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 2 END + case d1.eye when 'Left' then d1.inject1 end as left_1st_injection , 
    CASE WHEN d2.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 2 END + case d1.eye when 'Right' then d1.inject1 end as right_1st_injection 
from data d1
left join data d2 on d1.id = d2.id and d1.eye = d2.eye and d1.dat > d2.dat and d2.inject1 = 1
order by d1.id, d1.dat
;


id  eye dat left_1st_injection  right_1st_injection
111 Right   2020-01-01T00:00:00Z    (null)  0
111 Right   2020-01-03T00:00:00Z    (null)  1
111 Left    2020-01-05T00:00:00Z    0   (null)
111 Left    2020-01-08T00:00:00Z    1   (null)
111 Right   2020-01-12T00:00:00Z    (null)  2
111 Left    2020-01-16T00:00:00Z    2   (null)
```